# How to create a duplicate copy of a SQL Server stored proc or view with a new name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, database-replication

Suppose I have a stored procedure proc_MyTestProc.

I want to create a backup copy of this proc called proc_MyTestProc_{timestamp}, and create a new instance of this proc in its place. Here is my current method:

1. Run sp_rename on proc_MyTestProc, appending the timestamp.
2. Run the new CREATE script for the new version of proc_MyTestProc.

The problem with this method is that it doesn't work with replication. The original procedure retains the same object ID. The procedure created in step #2 is what I want to be replicated to another DB, yet it has a new object ID, so it doesn't replicate.

Is there an alternative to SP_RENAME that creates a copy of the object with a new object ID?

I am running SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Consider using [source control](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/12/is-your-database-under-version-control.html) instead

Comment: @Andomar +1 I was about to suggest the same thing. I can't stand seeing 15 old, outdated versions of a stored proc with old timestamps appended to the names.

Comment: @Andomar: I agree since tortoise is free.  My answer is just to show how to do it, not solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @old VARCHAR(255),
        @new VARCHAR(255),
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @myid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

SET @myid = NEWID();


SELECT @old = 'invoice_validation_sp', @new = @old + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(), 112)

SELECT @sql = REPLACE(OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID),@old, @new) 
FROM sys.procedures 
WHERE name = @old

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

You can always do something like this...

Comment: only issue I see is that you are doing a substring search and replace. So it could break the proc if it contains the string somewhere in the proc code. For example, suppose invoice_validation_sp calls invoice_validation_sp_helper.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  You could just change the search to "create proc [dbo].[invoice_validation_sp]"